# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. - no solution

Tags: angular, rxjs, httprequest, ngfor

I have a little problem with my code. I have 2 HTTP requests and after receiving the data I merge them together but when I try to loop through the final array I get the error displayed in the title.

I read other posts where they said that the returned thing is not an array but an object. I checked it and I receive a proper array. Here it is (sorry for the external link):
https://gyazo.com/e41ba0d77765cac5b871a0c80c99073a

What am I doing wrong here? I used type 'any' everywhere to make things easier for the time being.
I gotta add that I first used this logic in my component (the merging logic) and with an 'async as' pipe I could solve the problem (it did not work without the 'as ...' part, I got the same error.

My service code:

```js
    export class CryptoItemsService implements OnInit {
      allCryptoInformationMerged$!: any;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {}
      // 1st HTTP request
      fetchAllCryptos() {...}
      // 2st HTTP request
      fetchMetadata() {...}
    
      mergeFetchedObjects() {
        this.allCryptoInformationMerged$ = forkJoin(
          this.fetchAllCryptos(),
          this.fetchMetadata()
        )
          .pipe(
            map(([prices, details]) => {
              const mergedObjects: any = [];
              for (const item of prices) {
                const currentDetailObject = details.find(
                  (detailObject: any) => detailObject.id === item.id
                );
                mergedObjects.push({
                  ...item,
                  ...currentDetailObject,
                });
              }
              return mergedObjects;
            })
          )
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.allCryptoInformationMerged$ = data;
            console.log(this.allCryptoInformationMerged$);
          });
      }
    
      getallCryptos() {
        this.mergeFetchedObjects();
        return this.allCryptoInformationMerged$;
      }
```

My component file code:

```js
    export class CryptoListitemsComponent implements OnInit {      
      cryptoItemGeneralDetails$!: any;
    
      constructor(private cryptoItemsService: CryptoItemsService) {}
    
      getCryptoData() {
        this.cryptoItemGeneralDetails$ = this.cryptoItemsService.getallCryptos();
      }
    }
```

My template code:

```html
    <app-crypto-item
          *ngFor="let item of cryptoItemGeneralDetails$; index as i; even as e"
          [cryptoItem]="item"
          [index]="i"
          [even]="e"
    ></app-crypto-item>
```

Comment: You need to read up a bit more on how Observables work maybe?  Remove the subscribe from the service and return the actual observable. Then in your template use an async pipe to subscribe to it.

Comment: As I learned there are two ways to subscribe to an Http request: one is the way you said and the other is we subscribe directly at the end of the pipe and we work with the data afterward. That's why I used this approach

Comment: getallCryptos will not return the data as mergeFetchedObjects is async. It won’t work like this.

Comment: So that's why. Thank you!:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`any` is actually making things harder for you, the typescript compiler would've told you a few things you did wrong otherwise.

For example you're assigning `allCryptoInformationMerged$` two completely different data types.

Here you're assigning it a `Subscription`.

```js
this.allCryptoInformationMerged$ = forkJoin(...).pipe(...).subscribe(...);
```

Here you're assigning it the result of the Observable, I'm assuming it's an array.

```js
.subscribe((data) => {
   this.allCryptoInformationMerged$ = data;
});
```

Note that calling subscribe does not immediately execute the callback function `(data)=>{this.allCryptoInformationMerged$ = data;}`. This function is only executed after your http requests emit results.

Then you return this property and use it in `ngFor`, which throws an error because it is a `Subscription` at first, which is not iterable.

```js
getallCryptos() {
    this.mergeFetchedObjects(); // Sets property to Subscription
    return this.allCryptoInformationMerged$; // Returns before property is set to array
}
```

`any` basically says *"Leave me alone I know what I'm doing"*. In my opinion it's especially important to stay away from it if you're using data types / functions you're not familiar with, because you *don't* know what you're doing yet (no offense). Typescript is there to help you as a developer, so you're only shooting yourself in the foot by not taking advantage of it.

---

Here's what a working example should look like

**Service**

```js
  // I use any[] here because I don't know what your array contains
  // But you should replace it with the actual data schema
  getallCryptos(): Observable<any[]> {
    // This is just your mergeFetchedObjects method without the subscribe bit
    // I changed the forkJoin parameter to an array of Observables 
    // since the version you were using is deprecated
    // forkJoin will also take the type of array returned
    // I used [any, any] because I know it is length 2 but I don't know the types 
    return forkJoin<[any, any]>([this.fetchAllCryptos(), this.fetchMetadata()]).pipe(
      map(([prices, details]) => {
        const mergedObjects: any = [];
        for (const item of prices) {
          const currentDetailObject = details.find(
            (detailObject: any) => detailObject.id === item.id
          );
          mergedObjects.push({
            ...item,
            ...currentDetailObject,
          });
        }
        return mergedObjects;
      })
    );
  }
```

**Component TS**

```js
export class CryptoListitemsComponent {
  cryptoItemGeneralDetails$ = this.cryptoItemsService.getAllCryptos();

  constructor(private cryptoItemsService: CryptoItemsService) {}
}
```

**Component HTML**

```html
    <app-crypto-item
          *ngFor="let item of cryptoItemGeneralDetails$ | async; index as i; even as e"
          [cryptoItem]="item"
          [index]="i"
          [even]="e"
    ></app-crypto-item>
```

Notice the `async` pipe in HTML is what actually subscribes to the observable: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Generally you want to wait until the last possible moment to subscribe. Otherwise you're juggling local variables and trying to pass them around, as you experienced.

Comment: OMG, you explained it so elegantly. Now I see what I did wrong. I used async pipe first when I wrote the mergeFetchedObjects method in my component but then I wanted to move it into my service and then I made things difficult myself it seems.
I'm still a beginner, indeed and this is my first ever project I create on my own but struggled a lot with types so I decided to go with any everywhere first and later fix it. It was a bad idea it seems. Thank you for the detailed answer, I appreciate it a lot and learned something new again. I'm really grateful!